# Java: ucanaccess hsqldb java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, eclipse, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I downloaded and installed the uCanAccess jars by following instructions from here:
[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)
I'm learning how to use the microsoft access db for java and this is the coding I used

```
package Main.Net;

import java.sql.*;


public class DataBase {

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;



    public DataBase() {

    }

    private void connect() {

        try {
            //String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver";
            //Class.forName(driver);

            String db = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/MyUser/workspace/Connectors_DB.accdb";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from Table";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()) {

                String username = rs.getString("Username");
                String password = rs.getString("Password");

                System.out.println(username + "\t" + password);
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataBase().connect();
    }
}
```

and when I run the java program, it comes with this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties;
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.getHSQLDBConnection(DBReference.java:354)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:206)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Main.Net.DataBase.connect(DataBase.java:23)
at Main.Net.DataBase.main(DataBase.java:42)
```

error is at this code:

```
String db = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/MyUser/workspace/Connectors_DB.accdb";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
```

does it have something to do with the version of the hsqldb? because if it does I already tried downloading other versions of hsqldb and the same error appears

here are the jars I'm using:

ucanaccess-2.0.9.3.jar

commons-lang-2.6.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

hsqldb.jar

jackcess-2.0.8.jar

so... how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, the immediate cause of the error is obvious.  As to how this situation can occur, there are several mechanisms, but the most common by far is mismatched jar files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers in [this thread](http://hsqldb.10974.n7.nabble.com/NoSuchMethodError-org-hsqldb-DatabaseURL-parseURL-Ljava-lang-String-ZZ-Lorg-hsqldb-persist-HsqlPrope-td3175.html) suggest, that there are multiple hsqldb-versions on your classpath. Maybe one of the other involved jars contains hsqldb as well? You can inspect them using a zip tool of your choice, or the command `jar -tf foo.jar`.